# Center a TextView: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/desc" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to center the second TextView but I can not ... This is the code, you know help me? Where is the error? I'm going crazy!

Comment: u mean make the text display in center of screen

Comment: What? I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean

Comment: explain me what u want to do ??

Comment: @FiocchiLuca adding a picture (can be very simple) showing the layout that you are trying to achieve can be very helpful for answerers of these android-layout questions.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your textview:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

But at the same time I would recommend to reconsider your layout as you're having 2 textviews taking the full screen.

**Edit**
`center` centers both on horizontal and vertical. If you need only on a specific axis, use one of:
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
or
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: I tried to put it but doing so puts me also centered vertically. How do I? You can not put two TextView in a layout?

Comment: `gravity="center_horizontal"`... +1 for reconsidering layout

Comment: Updated the answer. You didn't mention what kind of centering you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/desc" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"   
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Always use match_parent instead of fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

What about setting it this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/desc"         />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Alternatively

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_contet"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"           
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/desc"             />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"           
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/desc"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```